# How to extract data from Google Sheets into a single Google Doc with new formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to take data from a selected range in a Google Sheets spreadsheet and have it wind up in a Google Doc with new formatting. To try and illustrate:

Here is an example of what the data from the Google Sheet would look like:

| Name | Title | Genre | Country | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Title1 | Genre1 | Country1 | Year1 |
| Name2 | Title2 | Genre2 | Country2 | Year2 |

And here is what the end result would ideally look like in a Google Doc:

Name1 – *Title1* – **Genre1** – (Country1, Year1)

Name2 – *Title2* – **Genre2** – (Country2, Year2)

I have searched to try and find information for how to accomplish this but all results seem to be focused on:

- Taking the data from a Google Sheet spreadsheet and creating *multiple* Google Docs from a template (for, say, a series of marketing letters)
- Just copying and pasting (as is) a Google Sheet spreadsheet or range into a Google Doc
- Data manipulation way beyond both my requirements and my comprehension

I have tried to utilize the tools within Google Sheets and Docs (at least as I understand them) and have not been able to ascertain how to make this happen. Looking through Sheets and Docs documentation I'm not finding any help.

I think I'm not using the right terminology in my searches, which is why I'm turning up nothing applicable. So I apologize if this has been answered previously and I'm missing it by looking in the wrong place with incorrect language. If someone could at least nudge me in the right direction, that would be excellent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As this is a custom solution unique for your use case, it'll be hard to find ready made scripts/solutions for this. However, this is entirely doable through Apps script.

Comment: `Data manipulation way beyond both my requirements and my comprehension` Not exactly sure what you mean by this... Would you care to elaborate.